# Convergence of increasing rearrangment

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ be measurable such that there are $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, $a<b$ fulfilling $[b,\infty)\subset A\subset [a,\infty)$. The right rearrangement of $A^{*}$ of $A$ is defined as $A^{*}=[c,\infty)$ where $c:=b-|A\cap [a,b]|$. Now we can define the increasing rearrangement as follows: For a function $u:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ fulfilling $\lim_{x\to -\infty} u(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} u(x)=1$, let the increasing rearrangement $u^{*}:\mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$ be the function which fulfils for all $t\in (0,1)$
\begin{align*}
\{x\in\mathbb{R}: u^{*}(x)\geq t\}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: u(x)\geq t\}^{*}.
\end{align*}
To show: Assume that $(u_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}:\mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$ is a sequence which converges pointwise a.e. to $u$. Then the sequence of increasing rearrangements $(u_n^{*})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is converging a.e. to $u^{*}$.

Comment: Sorry, what is $c = b - |A \cap [a,b]|$? $A \cap [a,b]$ maybe an uncountable set, or what is the exact meaning of $c$?

Comment: Since $[b,\infty)\subset A \subset [a,\infty)$ it follows $A\cap [a,b]\subset [a,b]$ will be a finite interval. Am I overlooking something? I have this example in mind: If $A= [1,2]\cup [3,\infty)$. Then $[3,\infty)\subset A\subset [1,\infty)$ and $c=3- |A\cap [1,3]|=3-1=2$ so that $A^{*}=[2,\infty)$ and $c=2$.

Comment: @DieterKadelka: I believe the OP is using $|S|$ to denote the Lebesgue measure of the set $S$.

Comment: I don't know what OP is, if you mean $|\cdot|$, then yes, this is the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I have one problem with your question: What is $A^*$ for $A := \{x \in \mathbb{R} : u(x) \geq t\}$? You have defined $A^*$ if $A$ is bounded from below, but $A$ as defined above need not be bounded from below, even for measurable $u$, F.i. what if $u(x)$ is strictly decreasing from $1$ to $0$?

Comment: @user99432 "OP" is internet-speak for "original poster", i.e., the person who made the original post (in this case, you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $u_n = 1_{[-n-1, -n] \cup [1,\infty)}$ (the characteristic function of $[-n-1, -n] \cup [1,\infty)$)? Then $u_n^* = 1_{[0,\infty)}$ for all $n$ but $u_n$ converges pointwise to $u = 1_{[1,\infty)}$, which has $u^* = 1_{[1,\infty)}$.

Comment: I think your example is very nice. Honestly I'm confused now. Your example doesn't fit into the definition of right rearrangement since $[-n-1,-n]\cup [1,\infty)$ is not an interval. This right rearrangement was introduced by Alberti and Belletini in https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002080050159 (Definition 5.5). So it seems that this definition is even not well-defined for $u$ only satisfying this limit conditions...

Comment: I'm baffled by this comment ... the right rearrangement is $1_{[0,\infty)}$ and $[0,\infty)$ is an interval. Is $1_{[-n-1, -n] \cup [1,\infty)}$ somehow not allowed as an initial function? Why?

Comment: I just thought that we need $[b,\infty)\subset A\subset [a,\infty)$ for the right rearrangement and $[-n-1,-n]\cup [1,\infty) does not fit in... but it seems that we don't...

Comment: @user99432: Note that $a$ and $b$ in your original definition are not explicitely given. They may be quite arbitrary but lead to the same $A^*$. Is this the problem?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. Maybe I have to change something. If $u$ is monotone can I conclude that $u=u^{*}$ ?

Comment: At least $\lambda$-a.e.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by $a$ and $b$ are not explicitely given ? They are real numbers, so $[a,\infty)$ has to be an interval

Comment: But they can be replaced by other values, f.i. $a$ by $a-1$ and $b$ by $b+1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your comments. The above statement is indeed false. Together with uniform convergence one can prove it!